# iptables and docker - what is the meaning of '!' character after chain name

Tags: docker, iptables

I am trying to understand the IP table configurations inserted by docker on my host.
Below is the output of `sudo iptables -t nat -S DOCKER`

For the output below, what does the ! after the chain name do?

```
-N DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-d98117320157 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d98117320157 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9202 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.23.0.3:9200
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8034 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8004
```

Comment: `man iptables` wasn't useful?

Comment: It says that if the interface is not docker0 or br-d98117320157 then apply that rule. You can find that by reading iptables documentation